# Align Grid Items with Various Heights

Tags: html, css

I've got a grid built using images and text beneath the image. And some of the images are of different height and I'm getting a "staircase effect" that looks like this.

[image]

What I'd prefer, is a version where all the text below the image is aligned and the images are
bottomed aligned.

I thought giving the `img`'s container `relative`positioning and then setting the `img`to `position: absolute;` with a `bottom: 0` would solve this but no dice.

If I give the `img`'s container a height in pixels it solves this, but when I start resizing the browser the `img` containers' height stays at a fixed height and doesn't look good on small screens.

Any idea on how to set the `img` container height automatically (for responsiveness) and for it to keep the images and text aligned?

I've setup a Codepen with my struggles here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/zFEdv

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use figure and figcaption and set layout with display:flex; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tBkvl

Comment: @GCyrillus That still doesn't solve the problem. As when you resize the browser the height stays fixed and you get huge spaces between the grid items.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css:

```
.row > ul > li{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

and remove `img` styling where you are positioning the image.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKExA)

Comment: This makes all the `img`s align top and the titles aren't aligned. I want all the images aligned to the bottom and for all the text to be in line too.